# Create system call function

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I need to create a system call function to get all child folders of the directory. But, I don't have any idea to do that. Can you give me some keywords or advice to implement that?

`asmlinkage long sys_get_child_folder(char* path, char** child_folder);`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a bad place for where-to-start sort of questions. What exact part of your task is problematic for you? If you want to know how to iterate files inside Linux kernel, then see that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458157/how-to-get-a-file-list-from-a-directory-inside-the-linux-kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'm smelling a XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/157291); what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Why the heck do you want to **create** a new system call for that? Just open the directory, enumerate all its entries and filter out those, that are not directory inodes. The canonical way to do this is to use the `opendir` function. https://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir

---

Also keep in mind that if you're writing code that's supposed to run inside the kernel, be aware that from inside the kernel, the ususal file system mechanisms are difficult to reach. The reason for that is, that filesystems spawn namespaces, which are depending on the task context; the only robust way to access files from within the kernel, is to have a userspace process open them and then hand the file descriptor to some kernel code. But this is strongly discouraged.

Comment: I try to make one system call function like http://www.cs.albany.edu/~sdc/CSI500/Fal13/Labs/OwnSyscallV3plus/OwnSyscallFE.html?fbclid=IwAR3DkiQSu6hytpcJQhm9jyTqz3EeTJol0xN6Zw738hOpTmRNle04F17s-h0 .

Comment: @ThànhTrần: Yes, you told us that. The question is why a system call? Why not use the functions you have readily available for user space? What is the problem that you're trying to solve, that forces you to do this inside kernel space?

Comment: @ThànhTrần: In my opinion that's a pretty poor extra question from your teacher: For one, it shows that your teacher doesn't understand that file system access requires knowledge about the so called "task struct" and how it creates mount name spaces. Also it states a problem for which a proper solution already exists in the wide open, so there's a high probability that students will just perform mindless copy and paste. Anyway, here's that particular implementation Linux already offers as a read-directory syscall: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/readdir.c

Comment: @ThànhTrần: Essentially the question your teacher posed expects from you to implement all the things `readdir.c` in the Linux kernal already does, plus a few other things that are part of the Linux VFS.

Comment: @dataworf Oh thank you, I very appreciate your help. Can you help me with one more problem? Can I get the last access child folder of one path inside the kernel?

Comment: @ThànhTrần: Assuming the inode information is updated (i.e. the file system *not* mounted with the `noatime` option), then it's again just a matter of enumerating the contents of a directory and sort by the last access inode stat field. And again, this is easier done from userspace, than from within the kernel.